# How to print a template in Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, javascript-framework, ember-data

i've this in my html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" template-name="index">
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
    {{#linkTo "index"}}<img class="logo">{{/linkTo}}
    <button {{action doLogin}}>Login</button>
</script>
```

and i've this in my router.js:

```
myTalk.Router.map(function() {
   this.route('index', {path:"index"});
});
```

but i've this error:

```
Uncaught Error: No route matched the URL '..../index.html'
```

thanks in advance and sorry for bad my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

First, `template-name` is not the right way to name your template. Change `template-name="index"` to either `id="index"` or `data-template-name="index"`

Second, you should not need to specify path to the `index` template. By default ember creates one for automatically, with path set to `/`. So in this case you don't even need a router definition

Finally, seems you're loading the page with URL set to `..../index.html` and that's not going to match anything in ember.

Here's a working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/XfDjm/1/